# Local HTML content in metro style app's

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am rewriting an app that we currently have working in iOS having trouble's with Windows 8 metro style app's.  In particular I'm unable to load *external* HTML content (and associated libraries i.e. Css and JavaScript).  When doing so I get a veriety of warnings and errors and\or JavaScript files not linked..

I believe I understand about sandboxing and the ms-appx vs. ms-appx-web context switching (in JavaScript project types) and have found the following.

1. Using an iFrame to load html from *within* the same project works, i.e. renders pages, executes linked javascript etc etc. (I believe that this also works loading when loading from a component project i.e. within the same package)
2. Using an iFrame to load from ApplicationData (where the files would be unzipped after downloading) does not work with either of the previously mentioned contexts. With an error similar to: `"The app can’t use script to load the file:///...AppData/Local/Packages/.../index.html because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app."` and no content shown, even though this is not being loaded by a script.
3. Using `launchFileAsync('file:///...AppData/Local/Packages/.../index.html')` in JavaScript loads and displays the content but does not link to external JavaScript files (or rather blocks them) and is much akin to executing a html file from your desktop and getting the `Internet Explorer restricts this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls` and the `Allow blocked content` button.

Unfortunately this content has to be delivered to the application remotely.  But all other aspects of the app can be changed. Other avenues of research that I'm following are; Using an in-app purchasing mechanism to download additional content. Building a custom browser control. Parsing file contents and pulling together into one monolithic page.

I would appreciate if anyone has any thought or has come across this themselves.

Comment: If your interested in my test html I have 3 files index.html, script.js and stylesheet.css here http://jsfiddle.net/YaCUw/